Excel: Countif with multiple criteria
Sheets("Create Summary").Range("B3").Value2 = _
    Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
        wsSourceData.[P:P], "Airports", wsSourceData.[AQ:AQ], "Not completed")

I'm trying to count all values other than "completed".

Try .CountIfs(wsSourceData.Range("P:P"), "Airports", wsSourceData.wsSourceData.Range("AQ:AQ"), "<>completed")

thnk  you, @taller
